# Error while building exe using npm pkg for nodejs executables

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nexe

I am getting the below error while running executable for nodejs. I tried including the assets in package.json but still the error won't go away.

**error: uncaughtException: File 'D:**\app\application_properties\CurrentEnv\application.properties' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script. **

**package.json**

```
"pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "node_modules/linebreak/src/classes.trie",
      "application_properties/CurrentEnv/application.properties",
      "app/binding.node"

  ]
}
```